# How to get the results report in regression in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using the following code to perform my regression.

```
clf = RandomForestRegressor(random_state = 42, class_weight="balanced")
k_fold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=0)
scores_mse = cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=k_fold, scoring = 'neg_mean_squared_error')
scores_e = cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=k_fold, scoring = 'explained_variance')
scores_me = cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=k_fold, scoring = 'max_error')
```

I want to get the results of multiple metrics such as `neg_mean_squared_error`, `explained_variance`, `max_error` etc. So, to get the each results, I have to re-run my cross validation models that takes a lot of time. So, I am wondering if there is any easy way in sklearn to get these scoring at once, without doing it multiple times.

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: this is one report: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html, but I don't think you are searching for this one. You could also write a function for this.

Comment: @PV8 yes you are correct, I am looking for regression results. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a nice help under [3.1.1.1](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html).

The script could be:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate

scoring = ['neg_mean_squared_error', 'explained_variance', 'max_error']
clf = RandomForestRegressor(random_state = 42, class_weight="balanced")
scores = cross_validate(clf, X, y, scoring=scoring)

scores['neg_mean_squared_error']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great answer. However, now I have the question what is the difference between `cross_validate` and `cross_val_score`. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: It always multiple metrics, train score and gives it back as a dictionary, I would say `cross_validate`is the advanced function for `cross_val_score`